# Why does alias to move into usr/local/bin fails

Tags: terminal, mv

I am trying to have an alias to move binaries into a folder on my path.
Currently I have:

```
alias addapp='sudo mv $1 /usr/local/bin'
```

Comment: A bash alias does not accept a parameter. You will need to rewrite this as a function. It would also help in future posts to include any error messages you get in invoking your commands.

Comment: The most important fact about aliases in `sh` and such: an alias replaces text with *text*. If you imagine `addapp` turns into `sudo mv $1 /usr/local/bin` in whatever command line you wanted to use it then you will see why it didn't work as you expected.